# How to use If command in the selenium ide?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I was searching the web for a long time. I'm trying to put `if` and `else` statements into this selenium IDE. The program itself doesn't provide any parameters, hints, or help. I saw a lot of results online where it's just java code, however I don't see anyway to enter code here.

Can someone show me an example of how to use this if and then statement?

[image]

Comment: store title of your website and assert with it if condition.

Comment: example please.

Comment: This page describes it well [selenium ide if/elseif](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs/selenium-ide/if)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Basic if condition example:**

[image: If condition test example Image link]

Example .side file. Save the below code in file with name as 'Test.side' and open in selenium ide

```
{
  "id": "92a8cfe0-a7ed-45a4-82c2-59f889cba0a6",
  "version": "1.1",
  "name": "test",
  "url": "",
  "tests": [{
    "id": "f78b739a-886c-4842-9d61-f83700ef29f6",
    "name": "test",
    "commands": [{
      "id": "ff43b0cf-7207-4599-8f11-3f90102cd1e2",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "open",
      "target": "https://in.yahoo.com",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "12efa973-069b-4254-9813-868d4a34876d",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "storeTitle",
      "target": "",
      "targets": [],
      "value": "title"
    }, {
      "id": "abde904f-6f3f-4a5a-b24a-59c3b2eafe2c",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "if",
      "target": "${title} != 'Google'",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "bb6640f2-6356-439f-b226-287030e8fa5a",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "open",
      "target": "https://www.google.com",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "ee3b8144-4981-460d-b707-e925e52ebe41",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "assertTitle",
      "target": "Google",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "f73c9836-4944-45aa-be07-9647991ffb36",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "end",
      "target": "",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "bcc2bd2b-5091-4b40-b499-f89c38e532bf",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "sendKeys",
      "target": "name=q",
      "targets": [],
      "value": "Hello world"
    }]
  }],
  "suites": [{
    "id": "e966e7ba-8ccd-418a-80e7-f99ac6c25f90",
    "name": "Default Suite",
    "persistSession": false,
    "parallel": false,
    "timeout": 300,
    "tests": ["f78b739a-886c-4842-9d61-f83700ef29f6"]
  }],
  "urls": [],
  "plugins": []
}
```

**If with else Example**

[image: If else Example Test Image Link]

Example .side file.

```
{
  "id": "92a8cfe0-a7ed-45a4-82c2-59f889cba0a6",
  "version": "1.1",
  "name": "test",
  "url": "",
  "tests": [{
    "id": "f78b739a-886c-4842-9d61-f83700ef29f6",
    "name": "test",
    "commands": [{
      "id": "ff43b0cf-7207-4599-8f11-3f90102cd1e2",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "open",
      "target": "https://www.google.com",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "12efa973-069b-4254-9813-868d4a34876d",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "storeTitle",
      "target": "",
      "targets": [],
      "value": "title"
    }, {
      "id": "abde904f-6f3f-4a5a-b24a-59c3b2eafe2c",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "if",
      "target": "${title} == 'Google'",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "bb6640f2-6356-439f-b226-287030e8fa5a",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "echo",
      "target": "I am in Yahoo Page",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "ee3b8144-4981-460d-b707-e925e52ebe41",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "assertTitle",
      "target": "Google",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "f73c9836-4944-45aa-be07-9647991ffb36",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "else",
      "target": "",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "a90e7c75-911a-46cb-ac52-a3fd394e6dfe",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "echo",
      "target": "I am in already in google Page",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "2b29d6fe-a670-4349-be18-794e85fbd498",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "end",
      "target": "",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "7f8ee438-4dae-4f34-b4b6-7a4a166acabf",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "sendKeys",
      "target": "q=name",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }]
  }],
  "suites": [{
    "id": "e966e7ba-8ccd-418a-80e7-f99ac6c25f90",
    "name": "Default Suite",
    "persistSession": false,
    "parallel": false,
    "timeout": 300,
    "tests": ["f78b739a-886c-4842-9d61-f83700ef29f6"]
  }],
  "urls": [],
  "plugins": []
}
```

**If with ElseIf Example**

[image: if with else if Example Test Image link]

Example selenium ide test file (.side)

```
{
  "id": "92a8cfe0-a7ed-45a4-82c2-59f889cba0a6",
  "version": "1.1",
  "name": "test",
  "url": "",
  "tests": [{
    "id": "f78b739a-886c-4842-9d61-f83700ef29f6",
    "name": "test",
    "commands": [{
      "id": "ff43b0cf-7207-4599-8f11-3f90102cd1e2",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "open",
      "target": "https://www.google.com",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "12efa973-069b-4254-9813-868d4a34876d",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "storeTitle",
      "target": "",
      "targets": [],
      "value": "title"
    }, {
      "id": "abde904f-6f3f-4a5a-b24a-59c3b2eafe2c",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "if",
      "target": "${title} == 'Google'",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "bb6640f2-6356-439f-b226-287030e8fa5a",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "echo",
      "target": "I am in Yahoo Page",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "ee3b8144-4981-460d-b707-e925e52ebe41",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "assertTitle",
      "target": "Google",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "f73c9836-4944-45aa-be07-9647991ffb36",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "elseIf",
      "target": "${title} != 'Yahoo'",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "a90e7c75-911a-46cb-ac52-a3fd394e6dfe",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "echo",
      "target": "I am in google Page",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "2b29d6fe-a670-4349-be18-794e85fbd498",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "end",
      "target": "",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "bcc2bd2b-5091-4b40-b499-f89c38e532bf",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "echo",
      "target": "I am out side the if condition",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }]
  }],
  "suites": [{
    "id": "e966e7ba-8ccd-418a-80e7-f99ac6c25f90",
    "name": "Default Suite",
    "persistSession": false,
    "parallel": false,
    "timeout": 300,
    "tests": ["f78b739a-886c-4842-9d61-f83700ef29f6"]
  }],
  "urls": [],
  "plugins": []
}
```

Comment: Welcome. I made the images as inline to improve readbility :)

Comment: I had missed two points: 1) You need to store text/value as a variable to run an "if" on it.  2) The "if" has to be matched with an "end".  Thanks!